# Why does Ubuntu not detect my SD card?

Tags: 12.04, sd-card

I can't mount my SD card. I'm using Ubuntu 12.04 LTS on an Asus K55V (Intel), and I have a sd card slot, but Ubuntu doesn't detect when I put a SD card in the slot. Not Ubuntu nor other program.

Comment: Make sure there's a formatted card in the slot and run the following commands: "sudo fdisk -l" and "blkid".  Paste the results back into your question so that we can have a look.

Comment: Have you checked the filesystem if the card is exfat you have to install exfat fuse for mounting it.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Run these commands from a command prompt:

```
sudo modprobe -r r852
sudo modprobe -r sdhci_pci
sudo modprobe r852
sudo modprobe sdhci_pci
```

This uses [`modprobe`](https://linux.die.net/man/8/modprobe) to unload and reload the device drivers ([in this case kernel modules](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/47250/209677)) to automatically detect the SD card into the kernel.

Source codes

- [r852 driver](https://web.archive.org/web/20161130191759/http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/drivers/mtd/nand/r852.c): Ricoh 85xx xD/smartmedia card reader driver
- [sdhci_pci driver](https://web.archive.org/web/20170307025026/http://lxr.free-electrons.com:80/source/drivers/mmc/host/sdhci.c): Secure Digital Host Controller Interface PCI driver

Comment: genius, it works in ubuntu 13.10 64

Comment: It works on ubuntu 14.04 32 also

Comment: Doesn't work for me. Ubuntu 14.04 64

Comment: Doesn't do anything for me in Ubuntu 12.04.

Comment: Works on Ubuntu 14.04 64-bit after running the command, then taking out the SD card and putting it back in again. Thanks a ton!

Comment: I tried all of this into my Ubuntu Studio 15.10 installation and... Nothing!!!

Comment: Worked on Ubuntu 14.04 64 bit, But after restart. thanks man...

Comment: This doesn't do anything on 18.04 and isn't any better than rebooting.

Answer (score 0):

For Broadcom Corporation BCM57765/57785, in addition to the answer below, I had to add lines to `modprobe.d` (before commands above)

```
$ sudo sh -c 'echo options sdhci debug_quirks=0x40 >> /etc/modprobe.d/sdhci-pci.conf'
```

**AND**

```
$ sudo setpci -s 00:1c.2 0x50.B=0x41
```

[[source]](https://gist.github.com/samgooi4189/2e6e18fd1d562acaf39246e5e386d7cb)