# Ubuntu 12.04.2 SD card is not detected

Tags: mount, sd-card, card-reader

My SD card is not being detected at all no matter what I do.

I am using Ubuntu 12.04, on:

```
HP Pavilion G6 2552sa 
Intel® Core™ i5-3210M CPU @ 2.50GHz × 4 
64-bit
```

The following commands were used with the SD card inserted.

```
lsusb

Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub 
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub 
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub 
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub 
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub 
Bus 002 Device 003: ID 05c8:0348 Cheng Uei Precision Industry Co., Ltd (Foxlink)
```

---

```
ls -la /dev/sd*

brw-rw---- 1 root disk 8, 0 Jan 30 17:04 /dev/sda 
brw-rw---- 1 root disk 8, 1 Jan 30 17:04 /dev/sda1 
brw-rw---- 1 root disk 8, 2 Jan 30 17:04 /dev/sda2 
brw-rw---- 1 root disk 8, 3 Jan 30 17:04 /dev/sda3
```

---

```
sudo fdisk -l

WARNING: GPT (GUID Partition Table) detected on '/dev/sda'! The util fdisk doesn't support GPT. Use GNU Parted.


Disk /dev/sda: 750.2 GB, 750156374016 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 91201 cylinders, total 1465149168 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x339d0cd5

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1               1  1465149167   732574583+  ee  GPT
Partition 1 does not start on physical sector boundary.


sudo lspci -nn

[sudo] password for verin: 
00:00.0 Host bridge [0600]: Intel Corporation 3rd Gen Core processor DRAM Controller [8086:0154] (rev 09)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Intel Corporation 3rd Gen Core processor Graphics Controller [8086:0166] (rev 09)
00:14.0 USB controller [0c03]: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family USB xHCI Host Controller [8086:1e31] (rev 04)
00:16.0 Communication controller [0780]: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family MEI Controller #1 [8086:1e3a] (rev 04)
00:1a.0 USB controller [0c03]: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family USB Enhanced Host Controller #2 [8086:1e2d] (rev 04)
00:1b.0 Audio device [0403]: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family High Definition Audio Controller [8086:1e20] (rev 04)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 1 [8086:1e10] (rev c4)
00:1c.1 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 2 [8086:1e12] (rev c4)
00:1c.2 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 3 [8086:1e14] (rev c4)
00:1d.0 USB controller [0c03]: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family USB Enhanced Host Controller #1 [8086:1e26] (rev 04)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge [0601]: Intel Corporation HM76 Express Chipset LPC Controller [8086:1e59] (rev 04)
00:1f.2 SATA controller [0106]: Intel Corporation 7 Series Chipset Family 6-port SATA Controller [AHCI mode] [8086:1e03] (rev 04)
00:1f.3 SMBus [0c05]: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family SMBus Controller [8086:1e22] (rev 04)
01:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Ralink corp. Device [1814:539b]
02:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8101E/RTL8102E PCI Express Fast Ethernet controller [10ec:8136] (rev 05)
03:00.0 Unassigned class [ff00]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTS5229 PCI Express Card Reader [10ec:5229] (rev 01)
```

Let me know if you need any other information, just ask and thank you for your help.

Comment: how about `gnome-disks`?

Comment: if your distro gnome based then `sudo apt-get install gnome-disk-utility`

Comment: this is weird. I used that and I have the latest gnome-disk-utility but the command is not found.

Comment: I think you must try `sudo apt-get install gparted` which supports GPT (GUID Partition Table) then `gparted-pkexec`

Comment: that is just showing my usual partitions, not my SD card. I've had Ubuntu for 4 days and had so many problems its unreal

Comment: I went through the same experience as yours with Ubuntu, please don't give up easily, your problem will be fixed, you will learn lots

Comment: I hope so, I have reinstalled 5 times because of commands not working how the tutorials said they would -.- any other advice on how to get my SD card working?

Comment: try `which gnome-disks` to locate gnome-disk

Comment: this happened verin@Bunt:~$ which gnome-disk
verin@Bunt:~$

Comment: then reinstall it `sudo apt-get install --reinstall gnome-disk-utility`

Comment: just noticed i forgot the s at the end but this happened still 
verin@Bunt:~$ which gnome-disks
verin@Bunt:~$

Comment: I reinstalled it using that exact command and then used "which gnome-disks" and again nothing came up

Comment: I'm sorry if you are getting as annoyed as I am at this, I have no idea why my laptop doesn't act like everyone elses

Comment: No, not at all. Be patient. I think something wrong with your system. We should diagnose why it acts up, please try this `locate gnome-disks` in my case it's in `/usr/bin/gnome-disks` you can give it a shot

Comment: again nothing comes up -.- verin@Bunt:~$ locate gnome-disks
verin@Bunt:~$

Comment: and nothing should be wrong, this is a fresh installation, this is the first thing im trying to do just to put a backup on my SD

Comment: you can test which commands work

Comment: such as? I know install works and the ones shown above

Comment: Did you try `sudo apt-get update` then `sudo apt-get upgrade`?

Comment: try `palimpsest` I think your version using palimsest instead of gnome-disks

Comment: will do when it has finished upgrading

Comment: that brings something up but my SD card is not listed

Comment: Reboot with the sdcard in the slot

Comment: It appears to be a bug https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/995743

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/95391/how-do-i-mount-an-sd-card

Comment: I already tried several solutions from that page before I posted my own question and no results

Comment: also the solution on launchpad did nothing -.-

Comment: What is the size of your SD?

Comment: Sometimes my USB stick gets stuck and I have to power off laptop, you can try power-off instead of rebooting

Comment: I have done both power off and reboot and my SD is 16GB

Comment: try `sudo apt-get install gphotofs` if it doesn't work check out this link http://askubuntu.com/questions/224333/why-does-ubuntu-dont-detect-my-sd-card

Comment: I have done both but with no results

Comment: i also did this 

verin@Bunt:~$ sudo lspci -nn

ill add the results above

Comment: does `sudo blkid` list it?

Comment: The solution provided here 
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/udisks/+bug/971876

Comment: no it does not :/

Comment: it appears that your card reader brandname is Realtek `Unassigned class [ff00]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTS5229 PCI Express Card Reader` so you must install its module, you should find a module compatible with your kernel version or you must download source code compile and install it

Comment: Just googled Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTS5229 PCI Express Card Reader and I have not got a clue what Im looking for. Im very new to linux

Comment: http://linuxterminal.org/issue-with-rts5229-pci-express-card-reader/ should solve your problem. @kenn maybe could write an answer based on that tutorial, and you can accept that. (since he is working on this issue with you for hours, I leave it for him, and because I'm lazy.)

Comment: What's more that it looks like those drivers are in the kernel from 3.8. What is your kernel version. Likely you just have to update it and problem solved.

Comment: Source file and instructions can be found in following link, pick up linux one http://www.realtek.com.tw/Downloads/downloadsView.aspx?Langid=1&PNid=15&PFid=25&Level=4&Conn=3&DownTypeID=3&GetDown=false

Comment: I know it's not that easy for you but you should give it a shot, I ll be back tomorrow

Comment: Thank you @falconer and kenn that last link worked perfectly, I can't believe it was that simple. And thank you kenn for trying all day, it looked like everything you told me to do should have worked

Answer (score 2):

If you have a Realtek Card reader follow this tutorial. It worked for me.

[linuxterminal.org/issue-with-rts5229-pci-express-card-reader](http://linuxterminal.org/issue-with-rts5229-pci-express-card-reader)

I assume it will work for other models as long as you download the right module from the Realtek website.

Comment: I'm glad you did it :), well done!