# How to access information on SD Cards Ubuntu 12.10

Tags: 12.10, sd-card, arm

I am running the arm version of Ubuntu 12.10. I need to install programs and view videos and such from an SD Card. Is that possible, and how could I accomplish that? Thanks in advance!
P.S. I am having a screen error, so I cannot see my entire desktop. For example, I can't access the toolbar or anything. It is very discouraging and I can't find a solution. If you have any ideas for that problem, answer my other question that addresses that. Or, put it in the comments here :)

Comment: check out previously asked question here http://askubuntu.com/questions/413171/ubuntu-12-04-2-sd-card-is-not-detected?noredirect=1#comment532347_413171

Comment: if can't access the toolbar and windows buttons then your windows manager is not working, try `metacity` window manager

Answer (score 0):

Hope you have removed any passwords of your SD card from the device which you created the password.

Comment: really? Is that all you got?