# Booting off an SD if Ubuntu doesn't natively recognise card

Tags: boot, sd-card

I want to set up my PC to boot Ubuntu off an SD card. My concern is, Ubuntu couldn't access my SD card until I used the solution posted [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/224333/why-does-ubuntu-not-detect-my-sd-card). Will this be a problem if I boot off the reader (assuming my BIOS has no trouble with it)?