# Ubuntu no longer detects SD cards

Tags: drivers, mount, 15.10, sd-card, dmesg

My card reader used to work fine but now it doesn't work, Here is my `dmesg` output:

```
[  290.581992] rtsx_usb_sdmmc rtsx_usb_sdmmc.0.auto: card claims to support voltages below defined range
[  292.222035] mmc0: error -110 whilst initialising MMC card
[  293.326746] mmc0: error -95 whilst initialising SD card
[  294.635082] mmc0: error -110 whilst initialising SD card
[  295.342597] mmc0: error -95 whilst initialising SD card
[  297.029076] mmc0: error -5 whilst initialising SD card
```

I tried multiple SD cards but none of them worked.
I've also tried solution [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/224333/why-does-ubuntu-not-detect-my-sd-card) but it doesn't make any change

Comment: I have the same problem. Using kernel 4.2.0-21-generic:

    `rtsx_usb_sdmmc rtsx_usb_sdmmc.0.auto: no support for card's volts`

    `mmc0: error -22 whilst initialising MMC card`

Comment: Any new information about this?